# Too high standards for upvoting on the site?

Tags: discussion, votes

I haven’t been on stats.SE very long, but I noticed that, compared to TeX.SE and SO, that I get less votes there on stats on answers and questions. So I started being conscious about the number of votes and it seems less in general.

I strongly believe that upvoting encourages new members to become or stay active on the site. Maybe something for all of us to be conscious about?